# Trying to dynamically allocate a parent pointer to a child inside a function is causing a segmentation fault

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

I've been working on understanding polymorphism and pointers and the concept somewhat escapes me. Luckily I have stackoverflow and google so most of my problems can be easily answered. However I've been trying to fix this segmentation fault for a few hours now with no luck and i'm uncertain as to what is breaking. I've stripped down everything to try and understand what's going wrong but I believe i'm missing a core concept in dynamic allocation.

I pass a character pointer into my function initialize, can I not dynamically allocate it inside a function? My code compiles but after giving an input for the (intended) switch there is a segmentation fault and the core dumps.

However if I exclude the function initialize and just run the code in my main function nothing breaks and zed is properly initialized to a barbarian type.

```
#include "character.h"//abstract class
#include "barbarian.h"//inherits character



void initialize(character *object){//gets the values for the object
                              //and lets user deem which type of object
    int x=0;
    cout<< "1. Barbarian."<<endl;
    cout<< "2. Gollum."<<endl;
    cout<< "3. Baba Yaga."<<endl;
    cout<< "4. Blue Men Group."<<endl;
    cout<< "5. Unicorn."<<endl;
    while(!(cin>>x)){
        cout<<"Input not valid."<<endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(10000,'\n');
    }
    cout<<"Input is: "<<x<<endl;               //debug line
    object = new barbarian("conan");           //seg fault here
    //down here is a switch that was excluded for this question
 }

void die(character *kill){//is now kill
    delete kill;
}               //this should delete the character after it is used

int main(){
    srand(time(0));//used for roll functions in the parent class
    cout<<(-time(0))<<"seconds until 1970"<<endl;//debug makes sure srand is
                                            //doing what I want it to

    character* zed;  //zed = new barbarian("conan");//In main this works
    initialize(zed);
    //zed = new barbarian("conan"); This works
    (*zed).atkRoll();
    (*zed).defRoll();
    die(zed);
}
```

I want to be able to pass a character pointer and then allocate it on heap as a class of the users's choice and use it in other functions called by main. I thought it would be possible to just pass the pointer and the take it as a parameter in the function. Then the local pointer would point to the same place as the pointer in main. As the function scope closes and the "object" is deleted then the pointer in main should remain pointing to the memory location for a barbarian. Is this not valid? What can I do as an alternative if so?
Can I not change the type of the pointer in main without telling the pointer?

I'm very confused >.<

Comment: You need to pass a pointer pointer. At the moment you're just passing the value of a pointer, then overwriting the local copy of that value inside your initialize function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should look like:

```
void initialize(character **object){
    /* ... */
    *object = new barbarian("conan");
}
```

Since otherwise you're not modifying the actual pointer, but the temporary copy of it. You need to pass a pointer to a pointer instead. Then, in  `main()`:

```
character* zed;
initialize(&zed);
```

*Explanation for the question in your last paragraph:*

You have `character* zed` in `main()`. That means, a pointer variable that contains an address (no meaningful address yet, just garbage):

```
zed = 0x12345678
```

Now you call `initialize(zed)`. In that function, there is a parameter of type "pointer to barbarian" called `object`. It's initialized to a copy of `zed`, i.e. to the value of `zed`:

```
zed = 0x12345678
object = 0x12345678
```

Now you call `object = new barbarian()`. Memory gets allocated and the address saved in `object`:

```
zed = 0x12345678
object = 0xABCDEF00
```

Now `initialize()` exits. `object` is temporary and gets destroyed. What remains:

```
zed = 0x12345678 (garbage)
object doesn't exist
```

*The fix is at the beginning of my answer.*

The segfault should occur here in `main()`, not in `initialize()`, I think:

```
(*zed).atkRoll();
(*zed).defRoll();
```

Because you call methods on uninitialized pointers to objects that (supposedly) try to access the objects' fields.

Also:

```
void die(character **kill){
    delete *kill; *kill == nullptr;
}
```

Though the idea of this methods looks very bad to me anyway.

Comment: Awesome! This worked for me. I think that where I got confused was that I thought the segmentation fault occurred when I tried to assign the object to the new barbarian. After some testing I found that the error actually occurred after the function closed, zed was still unassigned and I tried to call member functions on it and the program was very confused.

Comment: Wow that is absolutely a wonderful explanation. You say that the idea of my delete method is very bad, however. Why is it bad? In my code I intend to be creating multiple character child instances that I need to then delete. Is it bad to have a function to delete because there is a better way of doing it? I just needed some way to free memory at the end of my program and that was all I could think of. I'm very new to dynamic memory.

Comment: Well, I first saw it as a member function, now I see it's a global one. Thenit's more or less fine, however, I'd just store the characters in a container or array and delete the whole array when necessary (i.e. program exit / reinitialisation of the universe / etc.) I mean, what's teh point of wrapping `delete` into a whole method of its own?

Comment: You're right. I actually plan on using an array later on but first I wanted to make sure that I could make two instances of characters that fight each other first. Then I want to compartmentalize the defense and attack roll functions into a main fight function and then my characters into arrays and so on. I really do want to thank you though, you helped a lot!