# I Am Having Issues with Passing Struct Pointers

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am issues with a homework assignment. We are working on binary trees and whenever I try to pass my head node to my `insert()` function the node is not being changed. This has lead me to believe that I am somehow not passing by reference, I just can't figure out where the mistake is, however. Thank you for any help in advance.

```
/*Linked List
**Code inspired by Linked List by Daniel Ross
**Code written by Collin Bardini
**Assignment 6
*/

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Our node
struct node {
    int data;
    node* left; //lower
    node* right; //greater
};

//function declarations
void insert(node * head, int);
void print_preorder(node * root);
void print_postorder(node * root);
void print_inorder(node * root);
int search(int data, node * root);

//main for testing the access functions
void main(void)
{
    node* headA = 0;
    node* headB = 0;
    const size_t as = 7;
    const size_t bs = 100;
    int a[as] = {1,5,4,6,7,2,3};
    int b[bs] = {118,119,158,166,163,123,108,116,117,184,165,137,141,111,138,122,109,194,143,183,178,173,139,
        126,170,190,140,188,120,195,113,104,193,181,185,198,103,182,136,115,191,144,145,155,153,151,
        112,129,199,135,146,157,176,159,196,121,105,131,154,107,110,175,187,134,132,179,133,102,172,
        106,177,171,156,168,161,149,124,189,167,174,147,148,197,160,130,164,152,142,162,150,186,169,
        127,114,192,180,101,125,128,100 };

    for (int i = 0; i < as; i++)
        insert(headA, a[i]);
    for (int i = 0; i < bs; i++)
        insert(headB, b[i]);

    print_preorder(headA);

    cout << "search 196: " << search(196, headB) << endl <<
        "search 137: " << search(137, headB) << endl <<
        "search 102: " << search(102, headB) << endl <<
        "search 190: " << search(190, headB) << endl;
}

// creates a new node and inserts it in the correct location in the tree
void insert(node * head, int d)
{
    //make a new node
    node *p = new node;
    p->right = 0;
    p->left = 0;
    p->data = d;

    if (head == 0) //list is empty
        head = p;
    else //append to tail end
    {
        node* c1 = head;
        node* c2 = head;
        while (c1)
        {
            if (d > c1->data)
            {
                c2 = c1;
                c1 = c1->right;
            }
            else
            {
                c2 = c1;
                c1 = c1->left;
            }
        }
        if (d > c2->data)
            c2->right = p;
        else
            c2->left = p;
    }
}
```

Comment: `type*` = pass by value, `type*&` = pass by reference

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: see my [answer to this identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35330331/trying-to-dynamically-allocate-a-parent-pointer-to-a-child-inside-a-function-is) and use double pointers in the `insert()` function.

Regarding the "pass-by-reference" part of the question, well it depends on what exactly you mean by these words. You are passing the *node* by reference, true, but you're passing the *pointer to the node* by value. Remember that pointer is just another variable holding a non-negative integer value (overly simplified, but still true).

Long answer: the modifying functions should use either double pointers or references to pointers. The reason is that, in a function definition like `void insert(node * head, int d) { /*...*/ }`, the *pointer* itself is passed by value. That is, a temporary copy of the original pointer is created, and modified inside the function. The actual pointer remains unchanged. I.e., in these lines:

```
// definition
if (head == 0) //list is empty
    head = p;

// client code
for (int i = 0; i < as; i++)
    insert(headA, a[i]);
```

The temporary local variable `head` is modified, not the `headA` variable that you pass to the function. See the linked question where I posted a schematics of what happens with the pointer values in this situation.
You can change to e.g. double pointers like so:

```
void insert(node ** head, int d) {
// snip...
if (*head == 0) //list is empty
    *head = p;
```

Or pass the pointer by reference.

Note: for read-only functions, such as `print...()`, you don't need to use a double pointer or any other pass-by-reference mechanism.