# Segmentation fault: 11 when using dynamic 3D array parameter

Tags: c++, gdb

using gdb to find the source of the Seg Fault I get this

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000001000082bf in matchCounters (input=..., size=5, 
    valid_entries=0x100020cd0 <VALID_REGIONS>, nums=0x7fff5fbff460, 
    counters=0x100020588 <VTT for std::__1::basic_ifstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >+8>) at akh70P3.cpp:524
524     cout << "counters[4][1] = " << counters[4][1] << endl;
```

## main()

```
double *** all_counters;
generateCounters(all_counters);
matchCounters(/*some more parameters here*/ all_counters[0]);
```

## matchCounters()

accessing counters here causes a segmentation fault: 11

```
void matchCounters(/*some more parameters here*/ double ** counters) {

    //this causes segmentation fault 11
    cout << "counters[4][1] = " << counters[4][1] << endl;
}
```

## generateCounters()

accessing counters here works just fine

```
void generateCounters(double *** all_counters) {
    all_counters = new double ** [2];
    //region counters
    all_counters[0] = new double * [VALID_REGIONS_SIZE];
    //move kind counters
    all_counters[1] = new double * [VALID_MOVE_TYPES_SIZE];
    for(int i = 0; i < VALID_REGIONS_SIZE; i++) {
        all_counters[0][i] = new double [CATEGORIES];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < VALID_MOVE_TYPES_SIZE; i++) {
        all_counters[1][i] = new double [CATEGORIES];
    }
    //this works just fine! why?
    cout << "all_counters[0][4][1] = " << all_counters[0][4][1] << endl;

}
```

Comment: In `generateCounters `, the first line `all_counters = ` means nothing to the *caller* of that function. You're just modifying a local variable, and ultimately, the caller's pointer remains unchanged. There are *hundreds* of duplicate questions for this, [such as **this** one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35330331/trying-to-dynamically-allocate-a-parent-pointer-to-a-child-inside-a-function-is)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
all_counters = new double ** [2];
```

The `all_counters` parameter is passed by value to `generateCounters()`.

This allocates a new array in dynamic scope, and assigns it to the parameter named "all_counters", in the function called `generateCounters()`.

The `all_counters` in your `main()` is not affected at all.

Instead of passing it by value, you should, instead, declare it in `generateCounters()`, `return` it from the function, and assign it to the variable in `main()`.

Comment: Holy... shit.... i have been working on figuring this out for hours and can't believe i didn't see that. Wouldn't chainging it to void generateCounters(double *** &all_counters) {} also work.
I'm testing that now as a matter of fact

Comment: Yes, this will work too. Some may scoff at this approach, but this is really a matter of personal taste.

Comment: You may have failed to notice, but virtually every one of your "Good news! Today on stackoverflow.com..." comments has been flagged and deleted. Please stop leaving them. They're snarky and not constructive, and they're only going to confuse new users who may not have a good grasp of English idiom. Please stop posting them.

Comment: @meagar are you talking to me or to sam? I don't think i've ever made such comments

Comment: @herteladrian Sam.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are instantiating the array inside the function `generateCounters()` but you are passing `allCounters` by value instead you need to pass it by reference or by pointer. You should change the function in this way:

```
void generateCounters(double **** all_counters) {}
```

or more C++ style:

```
void generateCounters(double ***& all_counters) {}
```